# Java based encryption library for Android

Tags: java, android, encryption

I'm looking for a java-based encryption library for Android. I am aware of the built-in encryption that Android offers. Don't want it. Google broke compatibility from one OS to another. My app cannot rely on that. I also looked at Bouncy Castle, which is what Android uses internally but modified. The footprint however is pretty big at around 1.5 meg. Spongy Castle is available but is just a wrapper for Bouncy Castle with the same footprint.

Anyone aware of any other libs?

Comment: what do you mean by "broke compatability from one OS to another"?  if you use javax.crypto interfaces within android you shouldn't have a problem...

Comment: define "broke compatibility"

Comment: @PeterElliott there was an issue with the SHA1PRNG, but you had to abuse the API to have issues with it. I'm not aware of any other issues...

Comment: To be more precise: Sun uses a proprietary, unspecified pseudo random number generator. If you seed this directly after creation it generates an identical stream of pseudo random numbers. That last part is also specific to Sun. Basically you should stick to a KDF instead of using SecureRandom. The deterministic behaviour of the Sun provider is currently useful for testing (possibly), not much else.

Answer (score 2):

From a Java perspective, pretty much the only two games in town are the built-in JCE providers and BouncyCastle.  Since Oracle's JCE stuff isn't in Android, you either get to use the modified BoucnyCastle built-in, or SpongyCastle.

There are a couple of other options out there (GNU has one as a part of their classpath libraries, which would probably fail your footprint requirements), but honestly, I would be very skittish about using another crytpography library.  They are used by such a small subset of people (pretty much everyone who isn't using the built-in JCE providers is using BouncyCastle) that they are unlikely to have been rigorously reviewed for security, and for that reason you should probably avoid using them.

If you are concerned about api breaking within the built-in APIs, I would just stick with SpongyCastle.  1.5mb is honestly not that much of a footprint.

Comment: Additionally, using ProGuard will strip down the unused bits, so not really a problem.